# filter pandas dataframe based on another data farme index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

is there anyway to filter the first dataframe based on the index of second dataframe and generate the output dataframe?
In first datafarme, we filterout the rows whose index are present in second dataframe.
first dataframe

```
          C1 C2 C3  C4
        A 1  1  1   1
        B 1  1  1   1
        C 0 0   0   0
        D 1 1   1   1
```

second dataframe

```
                C1  C2  C3  C4
           A    1   1   1   1
           C    1   1   1   1
```

Output dataframe

```
                C1  C2  C3  C4
           B    1   1   1   1
           D    1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)]
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
B   1   1   1   1
D   1   1   1   1
```